# Nativescript Plugin Specify Pod Version in Podfile

Tags: ios, angular, cocoapods, nativescript

I am currently working on creating a plugin that is a wrapper around an iOS SDK. I need to use an older version of the SDK but I can't figure out how to specify the pod version to download and use. I am using the Podfile in the platforms folder > iOS. It looks like this.

```
pod 'AccountKit', '5.0.1'
```

But the problem is, it's downloading and installing the newest version automatically (5.3.0), as I can tell from the console. Am I specifying the version wrong, or is this a bug? I saw examples (non-nativescript projects) that setup their podfile this way. Is it different for Nativescript?

If it means anything, I am using {N} 6.0.3 and Angular.

Comment: Did you rebuild the plugin & try a clean build?

Answer (score 1):

try this 
`pod 'AccountKit', '<= 5.0.1'` 
This will install version 5.0.1 and any lower version.
For more detailed documentations, [click this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html).